# set Javascript parameters as key in viewdata,tempdata?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

"Hi I am new to MVC so sorry if this sounds silly ,but please could anyone tell me how to set javascript parameters as keys in viewdata or tempdata.. the problem is that i want to set display property of certain elements in my view any want them to persist after a post back following is the code for same .

```
function VisibleColunms(Cssclass) {
    $("."+Cssclass).toggle(500);
    if (@Viewdata[Cssclass] != null && @Viewdata[Cssclass]  != "none") {
      @Viewdata[Cssclass] ="block"

    } else {
        @Viewdata[Cssclass] = "none"

    }      
}
```

please suggest any way around if possible for the same ,NOTE: I cannot user hidden fields coz of updating target div using ajax .thank you in advance.

Comment: You cant. `ViewData` is server side code and javascript is client side code.

Comment: They're different (server vs client-side code). You can't simply assign JS variables to `ViewData` in view side.

Comment: ny ways thank u all ..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewData["LoadData"]));
```

it will help you for converting viewdata or temp data to javascript object or 
javascript value. but the thing is it perfoctally work in views once try in script file also.

Comment: That is not what OP is asking!